# OpenLayers georeference location is not correct

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have OpenLayers plugin installed.  None of the OpenLayers sources display in the correct location.  For example, Google hybrid displays multiple worlds tiled together.  My georeferenced shapefile data displays in correct location.  Project has EPSG:3857 for projection.  Same configuration and data works and displays correction on `Windows Vista` computer.

I am running QGIS 2.2, `Windows 8.1`.

Comment: Please update to 2.6 and the latest version of the Openlayers plugin and report back if the error persists